# Make mandatory one of two options

Tags: spring-shell

I have a command like this

```
@CliCommand("show user")
public String showUser(
        @CliOption(key = {"email"}) String email,
        @CliOption(key = {"id"}) long id) {
    //return user by id or by email
}
```

I want to make one of the two option mandatory.

```
show user --id 5 //valid
show user --email user@email.com //valid
show user //not valid
show user id 5 --email user@email.com //not valid
```

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to handle the validation inside the command implementation itself (and throw some exception if both or none of your options are set).

The `id` option parameter should be set to type `Long` instead of `long` then.

Comment: I hoped that Spring shell provided out of box solution for this problem.